# Unable to connect component to Redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to connect my component CMSForm to the Redux store but have not been able to do so. Here is my:

Reducer:

```
const cmsDefaultState = {
  cmsNum: "",
  facilityName: ""
};

export default (state = cmsDefaultState, action) => {

  switch (action.type){

    case 'SET_CMS_ID':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        cmsNum: action.cmsNum
      });

    case 'SET_FACILITY_NAME':
      return [
             ...state,
              action.facilityName
          ];

    default:
      return state;
  }

};
```

Store:

```
import { createStore} from 'redux'
import CMSReducer from './CMSReducer.js'

export default () => {
  const store = createStore(CMSReducer);
  return store;
};
```

Selectors:

```
export const getCMSNum = store =>
  store.cmsNum

export const getFacilityName = store =>
  store.facilityName
```

Methods:

```
export const setCMSId = (cmsNum = '') => ({
  type: 'SET_CMS_ID',
  cmsNum
});

export const setFacilityName = (facilityName = '') => ({
  type: 'SET_FACILITY_NAME',
  facilityName
});
```

This is the component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { setCMSId } from '../redux/methods'
import { getCMSNum } from "../redux/selectors";

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { CMSReducer } = state
  return { CMSForm: CMSReducer }
}

class CMSForm extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      cmsCertificationNumber: '',
      facility_name: ''
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleCmsNumber = this.handleCmsNumber.bind(this);
  }

  handleCmsNumber = () => {
    // dispatches actions to add todo
    debugger
    setCMSId(this.state.cmsCertificationNumber);
    alert("CMS Number: " + this.state.cmsNum);

  } // end of HandleCMSNumebr

  handleChange(event) {
   this.setState({cmsCertificationNumber: event.target.value});
 }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

        <input type="text" value={this.state.cmsCertificationNumber} onChange={this.handleChange} />

        <button className="update-cmsNum" onClick={this.handleCmsNumber}>
          Find
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
} // end of component

export default connect(state => ({ cmsNum: getCMSNum(state) }))(CMSForm);
```

If you see in this small snippet of code, I'm trying to set the CMS ID.

```
setCMSId(this.state.cmsCertificationNumber);
    alert("CMS Number: " + this.state.cmsNum);
```

And if anyone wants to see my index.js, here it is:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './redux/configureStore.js'

import { setCMSId } from './redux/methods.js'
const store = configureStore();

// store.dispatch(setCMSId("Hello"));
// console.log("[" + store.getState().cmsNum + "]");

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
  <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

But this doesn't seem to trigger the store either. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong? The CMSForm component is inside my `App.js`, where I don't have any mention of the Redux store. I only have it inside my `index.js` So not sure where I'm going wrong or what to do.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Are you getting the store as props in the component?

Comment: No, I'm not. How should I do that? @blankart

Comment: Try printing ```props.cmsNum``` in your case in the actual component

Comment: That works. But the issue is when calling setCMSId which gives me an error as undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things you need to correct:

1. Here you're returning an array but your state is an object.

   ```
   case 'SET_FACILITY_NAME':
      return [
             ...state,
              action.facilityName
          ];
   ```
2. If you take a look at this line of code:

   `setCMSId(this.state.cmsCertificationNumber)`

   you're just calling the function that returns an object.  You should dispatch the action.
3. You have an unused function

   ```
   function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const { CMSReducer } = state
    return { CMSForm: CMSReducer }
   }
   ```
4. You're not using the state that is mapped to the props here:

   ```
   export default connect(state => ({ cmsNum: getCMSNum(state) }))(CMSForm);
   ```

**Update**

You can use dispatch in this way:

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { setCMSId } from '../redux/methods'
import { getCMSNum } from "../redux/selectors";


class CMSForm extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            cmsCertificationNumber: '',
            facility_name: ''
        };
    }

    handleCmsNumber = () => {
        // to dispatch the `setCMSId` action.
        this.props.setCMSId(this.state.cmsCertificationNumber);

    } // end of HandleCMSNumebr

    handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({ cmsCertificationNumber: event.target.value });
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.cmsNum);
        return (
            <div>

                <input type="text" value={this.state.cmsCertificationNumber} onChange={this.handleChange} />

                <button className="update-cmsNum" onClick={this.handleCmsNumber}>
                    Find
        </button>
            </div>
        )
    }
} // end of component

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ cmsNum: getCMSNum(state) });
const mapDispatchToProps = {setCMSId};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CMSForm);
```

Comment: Thanks! 

1. Fixed 
2. How do I dispatch the action? Do I say this.props.setCMSId? Because that gives me an error too 
3. I saw this function on the Redux tutorial, not sure what to do with it? 
4. How do I change this? 

Sorry.. I'm new to Redux. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @coding-healthcare - Updated my answer. Note that there are multiple other ways to dispatch an action.

Comment: Thanks a lot! One issue tho is here: 
this.props.setCMSId(this.state.cmsCertificationNumber);
    console.log("[" + this.props.cmsNum + "]"); I'm trying to check whether the CMS ID has been set correctly but it comes back with empty. So I don't think it's set correctly?

Comment: Because one thing - props.setCMSId() doesn't work, I had to use this.props

Comment: Alright thank you. Would you suggest that I check the console to check if it's been set? Where should I be logging? Thanks again!

Comment: @coding-healthcare `this.props` is the correct way because you have a class-based component.

Comment: @coding-healthcare You can log the value of `this.props.cmsNum` in the render function before returning the JSX. See my updated answer.